# I am unable to run a python file

Tags: python, cmd

I get this errors quite often when trying to run a python file using `CMD` :

> Can't open : [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I have tried both: `cd <path>` where path is folder where file is saved; and python `<path\filename>` . Both give the exact same error. 
How to get rid of it?

Comment: The errors occours because your path is wrong. Please show some examples/commands of what you did.

Comment: Did you type ```python filename.py```  where the file is?

Comment: This error comes when you run command : python file.py and your command does not find your file.py in that folder.

Comment: @TK i have pyfile in desktop, so i wrote python C:\Users\programmersd\Desktop\pyfile.

Comment: @PéterLeéh i did. first i wrote cd folder path, then i wrote python pyfile.py

Comment: @Omkar But i have the file in that folder only, i mean the folder path is not wrong

Comment: i have another file named get-pip, which i am unable to run but i am able to tun pyfile. i write the command in exact same way

Comment: always show full error message. Maybe it has no problem to open script but maybe script uses `open(somefile)` and it has problem to open `somefile`.

Comment: C:\Users\programmersd>python C:\Users\programmersd\Desktop\get-pip.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\programmersd\Desktop\get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory @furas

Comment: Probably there is a dependency in ```get-pip.py``` which is not found. Try to ```cd``` to the folder first (or add the missing file, you did not show us what comes after the ```FileNotFoundError```).

Comment: why don't you go to folder `Desktop` - `cd Desktop` - and run from `Desktop` - `python get-pip.py`.  You can also use `dir` to check if this folder has name `Desktop` or something similar. And inside folder `Desktop` you can use `dir` to check if this folder really exists file `get-pip.py`